# Excel VBA If ElseIF else

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Im having a little trouble with a code in excel vba. My goal is convert the following if statement to a VBA macro.

The if Statement:

```
'=IF(R8="W",
'IF(L8>0,L8,
'IF(ABS(L8)<ABS(V7),L8,
'IF(N8+L8<0,L8+Z7,-V7))),

'IF(R8="A",
'IF(L8>0,(V7/(V7+Z7)*L8),
'IF(ABS(V7/(V7+Z7)*L8)>V7,-V7,(V7/(V7+Z7)*L8))),

'Added H not tested it yet
'IF(AND(R9="H",-L9>Z8),Z8+L9,0)

'IF(R8="C",
'IF(L8>0,L8/2,
'IF(AND((-L8/2)<V7,(-L8/2<Z7)),L8/2,
'IF(AND(V7<=0,Z7<=0),L8/2,
'IF(Z7+L8>0,-V7,-V7+(L8+Z7+V7)/2)))),0)))
```

What I want to do is that If there is a W in column R, I want it to check if the amount in Column L is great that zero, if it true, return the amount in column L. If false check if the absolute value of the amount in column L is less than the absolute value of the amount in column V. If true, return the amount in column L otherwise sum the amount in column N and column L. If the sum is less than zero return the sum of the amount in column L and Z. If it's false return the amount in column v (make it negative).

My attempt to solve it.

```
   Private Sub looping()
   Dim rw_cnt As Integer
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   rw_cnt = 8
   Do While Sheets("Personal").Range("R" & rw_cnt).Value <> ""

   If Sheets("Personal").Range("R" & rw_cnt).Value = "W" Then

        'I am having difficulties on this section. 
        Sheets("Personal").Range("V" & rw_cnt).Select
        If "=RC[-8]" > 0 Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]"
        ElseIf Abs("=RC[-8]") < Abs("=R[-1]C[2") Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]"
        ElseIf ("=RC[-6]" + "=RC[-8]") < 0 Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]" + "=R[-1]C[6"
        Else
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-1]C[7"
        End If

        Sheets("Personal").Range("Z" & rw_cnt).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=0"
  End If

  rw_cnt = rw_cnt + 1
  Loop
  MsgBox ("Done!!!")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KiVg.png

Comment: Are you trying to insert a formula into the cell, or are you trying to place the actual value into the cell?

Comment: And I assume the Excel formula you are trying to replace has a `,FALSE)` after the bit you showed (or, at least, a `)`) - is that correct?  Or are you trying to write a macro so that it leaves the current value in column T unchanged if column R does not contain a "W"?

Comment: And which column are you trying to put the result into?  (Your current code doesn't line up with the formula in the question - e.g. you are looking to see whether column T contains "W" in your code but the question talks about column R containing "W".  And your code is updating either column V or column Z, but your question says that column V is one of the inputs into the formula.  Etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, it's take your `...Range("V" & rw_cnt)` cell and see if it's greater than 0, less than an absolute value of a cell left one col. and down 2 rows, or if two offset cells are less than 0...

How does this work?

```
'I am having difficulties on this section.
Dim myCel As Range
Set myCel = Sheets("Personal").Range("V" & rw_cnt)
With myCel
    If .Offset(0, -8).Value > 0 Then
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]"
    ElseIf Abs(.Offset(0, -8).Value) < Abs(.Offset(-1, 2).Value) Then
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]"
    ElseIf (.Offset(0, -6).Value + .Offset(0, -8).Value) < 0 Then
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]+R[-1]C[6]"
    Else
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-1]C[7]"
    End If
End with
```

Basically, where you have a formula, VBA is just interpreting that as a String.  Replace the R1C1 references with an Offset, and then it should work for you.  If the above doesn't do anything, or is incorrect, let me know...but see if you can understand what I'm trying, as I believe that's the crux of your main issue.

edit: Instead of `ActiveCell`, use `myCell`.

Edit2:
Edit: Here's a "tighter" version of the code:

```
Private Sub looping()
Dim rw_cnt As Long, lastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Sheets("Personal")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Row
    For rw_cnt = 8 To lastRow
        If .Range("R" & rw_cnt).Value = "W" And .Range("R" & rw_cnt).Value <> "" Then
            'I am having difficulties on this section.
            Dim myCel As Range
            Set myCel = Sheets("Personal").Range("V" & rw_cnt)
            With myCel
                .Select
                If .Offset(0, -8).Value > 0 Then
                    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]"
                ElseIf Abs(.Offset(0, -8).Value) < Abs(.Offset(-1, 2).Value) Then
                    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]"
                ElseIf (.Offset(0, -6).Value + .Offset(0, -8).Value) < 0 Then
                    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]+R[-1]C[6]"
                Else
                    .FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-1]C[7]"
                End If
            End With
            .Range("Z" & rw_cnt).FormulaR1C1 = "=0"
        End If
    Next rw_cnt
End With                     'Sheets("Personal")

MsgBox ("Done!!!")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell` ?!?!  You should be ashamed of yourself ! ;)  (`myCel` perhaps?)

Comment: @YowE3K - I know, I know! Ah, I was so focused on making the `mycel` reference, I didn't put it together that `Selection` *was* the `ActiveCell`. :O

Comment: A nice `With myCel` block wouldn't go astray either ;)  (I'll shut up now. :D)

Comment: I made the changes and incorporated the edit as well. The code is not executing past the: ElseIf Abs(myCel.Offset(0, -8).Value) < Abs(myCel.Offset(-1, 2).Value) Then

Comment: @user7994251 - (I edited the code, using `With` per YowE3K's note, it makes it a little easier to read I think) - Hm, I just tested the code and it's working for me.  If you step through the code with `F8`, does it skip that line, or just stop working, or...?  It may help to have a sample of the numbers you have to see if there's something else perhaps causing it to skip?

Comment: @BruceWayne When I use F8 it just stops working. How can I send you the sample of data?

Comment: @user7994251 - Just copy/paste some data into your original post (click "Edit") and format it with `{}` so it looks okay. Or, at the very least, a screen shot of your info.  If it's sensitive info, just make up numbers or otherwise obfuscate the info.

Comment: @BruceWayne I made the edits. The data is in the link I provided at the end of the question.

Comment: @user7994251 - Thanks. I duplicated some of the data, and it's looping properly through the code. See my edit, I tweaked it a little to (hopefully!) make sure it works.  Note that this part, `.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]+R[-1]C[6]"`, will look to Column `AB`. Is that the column you want? Or did you want to look at Col. `Z`? In which case, change it to `.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]+R[-1]C[4]"`

Comment: .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]+R[-1]C[6]" is correct. The if statement should be returning the result in column T and not column V. "Set myCel = Sheets("Personal").Range("T" & rw_cnt)". That was my mistake.                                               It's working! Thanks for your help this far.                                     Instead of having to specify the last row all the time, "lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Row', how can I have the loop end when there is no more data in column L.

Comment: @user7994251 - Do you mean you want `Set myCel = Sheets("Personal").Range("T" & rw_cnt)`? That would use the value in column T to determine all the `If` offsets are accurate...or if `myCel` is correct, then just adjust the `RC` value(s)...Edit: Just change `.Cells(.Rows.Count,22)...` to `.Cells(.Rows.Count,12)...` (the `12` refers to the column Number, which Col. L is...

Comment: Makes sense. It works!! I will add the remaining part of the If statement to the macro using your updated statement and let you know if I have any questions. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user7994251 - happy to help, glad it's working!  If you don't mind, you can mark the post as the answer by clicking the check mark left of the post itself (under the up/down arrows).

Comment: For the line after the end with (.Range("X" & rw_cnt).FormulaR1C1 = "=0") if the value is equal to zero, the macro is fine, if the value is not, the macro stops running. I tried changing the line to (.Range("x" & rw_cnt).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]-RC[-4]") and got the error.

Comment: @user7994251 - What do you mean? if the value you're trying  to set is 0, it's okay, but if you change to `.Range("Z" & rw_cnt).FormulaR1C1 = "RC[-12]-RC[-4]"` it gets an error?  What error does it throw?

Comment: I mean that When I use F8 it just stops working at that line.

Comment: @user7994251 - "it stops working", you mean it literally just ends the sub? or it throws an error, or it skips the line and goes to another one, etc.?

Comment: @user7994251 I'll take another look, but his might be better as a new question...IIRC I couldn't duplicate the error.